# pasar datos de un formulario a otra pagina y en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

no se si alguno de ustedes pueda ayudarme con una duda, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario, los registros de este mismo deben guardarse en una tabla en otra pagina diferente
tengo esto que vi en esta pagina de aqui "https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/JavaScript/v5201-Llenar-una-tabla-con-los-valores-de-un-formulario.html#comentarios   (es la version 1 con la que estoy trabajando)" pero lo que quiero es que los datos vayan a otra pagina (en una tabla) no que esten en la misma que el formulario

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box;font-family:arial;}
    .hide {display:none;}
    .right {text-align:right;}
    .error {border:1px solid Red;}
 
    .nombre {width:100%}
    .formulario {text-align:center;width:400px;border:1px solid #eee;padding:10px;}
    .formulario label,.formulario label~input {
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
    .formulario label {text-align:right;padding-right:20px;}
    .formulario>div {margin-top:10px;overflow:hidden;}
    .agregar {
        background-color:green;
        border-color:green;
        color:white;
    }
 
    #listado {
        border:1px solid #eee;
        margin-top:20px;
        width:400px;
    }
    #listado th {background-color:#eee;padding:5px 10px;}
    #listado input[type=button] {
        background-color:Red;
        border-color:Red;
        color:white;
    }
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<form class="formulario">
    <div>
        <label>Nombre del alumno</label><input type="text" name="nombre">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Edad del alumno</label><input type="number" name="edad" min="3" max="100">
    </div>
    <div>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="agregar">
    </div>
</form>
 
<table id="listado" class='hide'>
    <thead>
        <th>Alumno</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
 
<script>
document.querySelector("input[class=agregar]").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    // cancelamos el evento submit
    e.preventDefault();
 
    var nombre=document.querySelector("input[name=nombre]");
    var edad=document.querySelector("input[name=edad]");
 
    // mostramos un error si no ha recibido el nombre
    if(!nombre.value)
    {
        nombre.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    nombre.classList.remove("error");
 
    // mostramos un error si no ha recibido una edad
    if(isNaN(parseInt(edad.value)) || parseInt(edad.value)<=0)
    {
        edad.classList.add("error");
        return;
    }
    edad.classList.remove("error");
 
    // añadimos el alumno a la tabla crando el tr, td's y el botón para eliminarlo
    var tr=document.createElement("tr");
 
    var tdNombre=document.createElement("td");
    var txt=document.createTextNode(nombre.value);
    tdNombre.appendChild(txt);
    tdNombre.className="nombre";
 
    var tdEdad=document.createElement("td");
    txt=document.createTextNode(edad.value);
    tdEdad.appendChild(txt);
    tdEdad.className="right";
 
    var tdRemove=document.createElement("td");
    var buttonRemove=document.createElement("input")
    buttonRemove.type="button";
    buttonRemove.value="Eliminar";
    buttonRemove.onclick=function () {
        // elimina la columna
        this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
 
        // Si no hay ningun alumno, escondemos la tabla
        if(document.getElementById("listado").querySelector("tbody").querySelectorAll("tr").length==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("listado").classList.add("hide");
        }
    };
    tdRemove.appendChild(buttonRemove);
 
    tr.appendChild(tdNombre);
    tr.appendChild(tdEdad);
    tr.appendChild(tdRemove);
 
    var tbody=document.getElementById("listado").querySelector("tbody").appendChild(tr);
 
    // eliminamos la clase que tiene oculta la tabla cando no hay ningun alumno
    document.getElementById("listado").classList.remove("hide");
 
    //limpiamos los valores del input
    edad.value="";
    nombre.value="";
    nombre.focus();
 
});
</script>
```

espero puedan ayudarme, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con localstorage.

Comment: crees que puedas ayudarme con un ejemplo porfis?, muchas gracias